# merging 2 dataframes of different size in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Initial loadout:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd
```

I have the following (made up for this example) data:

```
In [36]:

df
Out[36]:
     Date       Expiry   Close  K  C/P  Vol    Qty  Delta   Use
0   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.500  -85 0.995   N
1   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.000  -94 -0.005  N
2   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.500  -48 0.922   N
3   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.889  -25 -0.079  Y
4   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.000  -75 0.877   N
5   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.492  98  -0.123  Y
6   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.000  74  0.807   N
7   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.649  -97 -0.193  Y
8   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.000  -24 0.696   N
9   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.944  32  -0.304  Y
10  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.000  -11 0.523   N
11  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.000  5   -0.477  Y
12  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.000  -11 0.330   Y
13  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.000  -46 -0.670  N
14  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.000  -96 0.263   Y
15  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 P   22.649  22  -0.737  N
16  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 115 C   25.000  100 0.189   Y
17  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 115 P   26.000  16  -0.811  N
18  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 120 C   28.000  13  0.108   Y
19  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 120 P   29.500  -3  -0.892  N
20  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 125 C   30.000  -50 0.018   Y
21  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 125 P   33.000  -84 -0.982  N
22  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  75  C   43.044  -4  0.950   N
23  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  75  P   41.545  38  -0.050  Y
24  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  80  C   41.042  38  0.922   N
25  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  80  P   39.404  -9  -0.079  Y
26  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  85  C   36.411  -34 0.877   N
27  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  85  P   36.926  -23 -0.123  Y
28  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  90  C   33.212  27  0.807   N
29  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  90  P   33.913  -30 -0.193  Y
30  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  95  C   29.907  -37 0.696   N
31  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  95  P   29.844  26  -0.304  Y
32  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  100 C   27.635  1   0.523   N
33  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  100 P   27.635  13  -0.477  Y
34  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  105 C   29.907  38  0.330   Y
35  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  105 P   29.844  -17 -0.670  N
36  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  110 C   33.212  -5  0.263   Y
37  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  110 P   33.913  -18 -0.737  N
38  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  115 C   36.411  -50 0.189   Y
39  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  115 P   36.926  42  -0.811  N
40  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  120 C   39.518  3   0.108   Y
41  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  120 P   39.404  50  -0.892  N
42  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  125 C   41.545  24  0.008   N
43  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  125 P   41.545  -30 -0.982  N
```

I added the 'USE' column to help in the understanding, it is not calculated per say

I need to generate a weighted regression equation using only the data where the absolute value of delta is in a range between 0.01 and 0.5

I also need to have the regression equation be specific to a given Date/Expiry set.

Below is the code I apply to get the fitted volatility from the regression equation y = ax^2 + x + c and the results are great . . .

```
def regress(df):
    y=df['Vol']
    x=df['K']
    z=np.polyfit(x,y,2, w=np.sqrt(abs(df['Delta'])))
    return pd.Series(z, name='Regression Coefficients "x power"', index=range(3)[::-1])

df=df[(abs(df['Delta']) <= .5) & (abs(df['Delta']) >= .01)]

group_cols = ['Date', 'Expiry']
coeffs = df.groupby(group_cols).apply(regress)

df2=df.merge(coeffs.reset_index(), on=group_cols)
df2=df2.rename(columns = {2:'X2',1:'X',0:'Const'})

df2['FitVol']=df2['K']**2*df2['X2'] + df2['K']*df2['X'] + df2['Const']
```

which gives me the below results:

​

```
In [67]:

df2
Out[67]:
      Date       Expiry   Close K  C/P  Vol    Qty  Delta  Use   X2           X        Const         FitVol
0   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.889  -25 -0.079  Y   0.025255    -5.065786   272.719847  29.086473
1   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.492  98  -0.123  Y   0.025255    -5.065786   272.719847  24.592595
2   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.649  -97 -0.193  Y   0.025255    -5.065786   272.719847  21.361446
3   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.944  32  -0.304  Y   0.025255    -5.065786   272.719847  19.393028
4   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.000  5   -0.477  Y   0.025255    -5.065786   272.719847  18.687340
5   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.000  -11 0.330   Y   0.025255    -5.065786   272.719847  19.244382
6   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.000  -96 0.263   Y   0.025255    -5.065786   272.719847  21.064155
7   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 115 C   25.000  100 0.189   Y   0.025255    -5.065786   272.719847  24.146657
8   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 120 C   28.000  13  0.108   Y   0.025255    -5.065786   272.719847  28.491890
9   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 125 C   30.000  -50 0.018   Y   0.025255    -5.065786   272.719847  34.099854
10  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  75  P   41.545  38  -0.050  Y   0.026669    -5.311644   293.741836  45.379281
11  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  80  P   39.404  -9  -0.079  Y   0.026669    -5.311644   293.741836  39.489208
12  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  85  P   36.926  -23 -0.123  Y   0.026669    -5.311644   293.741836  34.932563
13  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  90  P   33.913  -30 -0.193  Y   0.026669    -5.311644   293.741836  31.709346
14  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  95  P   29.844  26  -0.304  Y   0.026669    -5.311644   293.741836  29.819559
15  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  100 P   27.635  13  -0.477  Y   0.026669    -5.311644   293.741836  29.263200
16  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  105 C   29.907  38  0.330   Y   0.026669    -5.311644   293.741836  30.040270
17  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  110 C   33.212  -5  0.263   Y   0.026669    -5.311644   293.741836  32.150768
18  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  115 C   36.411  -50 0.189   Y   0.026669    -5.311644   293.741836  35.594696
19  8/10/2015   10/20/2015  99  120 C   39.518  3   0.108   Y   0.026669    -5.311644   293.741836  40.372052
```

## Here is the problem

I need to have the regression variables and FitVol apply to all of the original data, not the data that was filtered to have the abs(Delta) be between 0.01 and 0.5

In order to calculate FitVol for all the original data I need to get the regression coefficients back to "all" of the original rows, just not sure how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Added By OP

In my searching I came up with something that is close . . .I get the needed result but I get repeating values, is thewre a way to select only one record for each original row of data?:

This is what I tried:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date', 'Expiry'])
```

The problem is obvious here:

```
Index   Date    Expiry   Close _x   K_x    C/P   _x Vol_x   Qty_x   Delta_x Use_x    Close _y   K_y    C/P   _y Vol_y   Qty_y   Delta_y Use_y   X2  X   Const   FitVol
0   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.50   -85.00  1.00    N   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
1   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.50   -85.00  1.00    N   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
2   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.50   -85.00  1.00    N   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
3   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.50   -85.00  1.00    N   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
4   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.50   -85.00  1.00    N   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
5   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.50   -85.00  1.00    N   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
6   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.50   -85.00  1.00    N   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
7   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.50   -85.00  1.00    N   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
8   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.50   -85.00  1.00    N   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
9   8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.50   -85.00  1.00    N   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
10  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  C   31.50   -85.00  1.00    N   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
11  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.00   -94.00  -0.01   Y   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
12  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.00   -94.00  -0.01   Y   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
13  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.00   -94.00  -0.01   Y   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
14  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.00   -94.00  -0.01   Y   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
15  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.00   -94.00  -0.01   Y   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
16  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.00   -94.00  -0.01   Y   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
17  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.00   -94.00  -0.01   Y   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
18  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.00   -94.00  -0.01   Y   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
19  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.00   -94.00  -0.01   Y   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
20  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.00   -94.00  -0.01   Y   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
21  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 75  P   30.00   -94.00  -0.01   Y   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
22  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.50   -48.00  0.92    N   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
23  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.50   -48.00  0.92    N   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
24  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.50   -48.00  0.92    N   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
25  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.50   -48.00  0.92    N   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
26  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.50   -48.00  0.92    N   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
27  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.50   -48.00  0.92    N   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
28  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.50   -48.00  0.92    N   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
29  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.50   -48.00  0.92    N   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
30  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.50   -48.00  0.92    N   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
31  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.50   -48.00  0.92    N   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
32  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  C   29.50   -48.00  0.92    N   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
33  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.89   -25.00  -0.08   Y   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
34  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.89   -25.00  -0.08   Y   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
35  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.89   -25.00  -0.08   Y   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
36  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.89   -25.00  -0.08   Y   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
37  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.89   -25.00  -0.08   Y   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
38  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.89   -25.00  -0.08   Y   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
39  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.89   -25.00  -0.08   Y   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
40  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.89   -25.00  -0.08   Y   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
41  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.89   -25.00  -0.08   Y   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
42  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.89   -25.00  -0.08   Y   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
43  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 80  P   27.89   -25.00  -0.08   Y   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
44  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.00   -75.00  0.88    N   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
45  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.00   -75.00  0.88    N   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
46  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.00   -75.00  0.88    N   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
47  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.00   -75.00  0.88    N   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
48  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.00   -75.00  0.88    N   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
49  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.00   -75.00  0.88    N   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
50  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.00   -75.00  0.88    N   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
51  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.00   -75.00  0.88    N   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
52  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.00   -75.00  0.88    N   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
53  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.00   -75.00  0.88    N   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
54  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  C   25.00   -75.00  0.88    N   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
55  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.49   98.00   -0.12   Y   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
56  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.49   98.00   -0.12   Y   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
57  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.49   98.00   -0.12   Y   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
58  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.49   98.00   -0.12   Y   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
59  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.49   98.00   -0.12   Y   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
60  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.49   98.00   -0.12   Y   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
61  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.49   98.00   -0.12   Y   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
62  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.49   98.00   -0.12   Y   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
63  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.49   98.00   -0.12   Y   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
64  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.49   98.00   -0.12   Y   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
65  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 85  P   25.49   98.00   -0.12   Y   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
66  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.00   74.00   0.81    N   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
67  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.00   74.00   0.81    N   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
68  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.00   74.00   0.81    N   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
69  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.00   74.00   0.81    N   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
70  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.00   74.00   0.81    N   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
71  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.00   74.00   0.81    N   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
72  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.00   74.00   0.81    N   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
73  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.00   74.00   0.81    N   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
74  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.00   74.00   0.81    N   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
75  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.00   74.00   0.81    N   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
76  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  C   22.00   74.00   0.81    N   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
77  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.65   -97.00  -0.19   Y   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
78  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.65   -97.00  -0.19   Y   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
79  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.65   -97.00  -0.19   Y   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
80  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.65   -97.00  -0.19   Y   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
81  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.65   -97.00  -0.19   Y   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
82  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.65   -97.00  -0.19   Y   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
83  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.65   -97.00  -0.19   Y   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
84  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.65   -97.00  -0.19   Y   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
85  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.65   -97.00  -0.19   Y   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
86  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.65   -97.00  -0.19   Y   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
87  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 90  P   22.65   -97.00  -0.19   Y   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
88  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.00   -24.00  0.70    N   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
89  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.00   -24.00  0.70    N   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
90  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.00   -24.00  0.70    N   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
91  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.00   -24.00  0.70    N   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
92  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.00   -24.00  0.70    N   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
93  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.00   -24.00  0.70    N   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
94  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.00   -24.00  0.70    N   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
95  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.00   -24.00  0.70    N   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
96  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.00   -24.00  0.70    N   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
97  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.00   -24.00  0.70    N   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
98  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  C   19.00   -24.00  0.70    N   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
99  8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.94   32.00   -0.30   Y   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
100 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.94   32.00   -0.30   Y   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
101 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.94   32.00   -0.30   Y   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
102 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.94   32.00   -0.30   Y   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
103 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.94   32.00   -0.30   Y   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
104 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.94   32.00   -0.30   Y   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
105 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.94   32.00   -0.30   Y   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
106 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.94   32.00   -0.30   Y   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
107 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.94   32.00   -0.30   Y   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
108 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.94   32.00   -0.30   Y   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
109 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 95  P   18.94   32.00   -0.30   Y   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
110 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.00   -11.00  0.52    N   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
111 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.00   -11.00  0.52    N   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
112 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.00   -11.00  0.52    N   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
113 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.00   -11.00  0.52    N   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
114 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.00   -11.00  0.52    N   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
115 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.00   -11.00  0.52    N   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
116 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.00   -11.00  0.52    N   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
117 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.00   -11.00  0.52    N   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
118 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.00   -11.00  0.52    N   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
119 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.00   -11.00  0.52    N   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
120 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 C   19.00   -11.00  0.52    N   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
121 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.00   5.00    -0.48   Y   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
122 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.00   5.00    -0.48   Y   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
123 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.00   5.00    -0.48   Y   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
124 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.00   5.00    -0.48   Y   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
125 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.00   5.00    -0.48   Y   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
126 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.00   5.00    -0.48   Y   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
127 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.00   5.00    -0.48   Y   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
128 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.00   5.00    -0.48   Y   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
129 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.00   5.00    -0.48   Y   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
130 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.00   5.00    -0.48   Y   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
131 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 100 P   18.00   5.00    -0.48   Y   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
132 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.00   -11.00  0.33    Y   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
133 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.00   -11.00  0.33    Y   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
134 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.00   -11.00  0.33    Y   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
135 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.00   -11.00  0.33    Y   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
136 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.00   -11.00  0.33    Y   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
137 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.00   -11.00  0.33    Y   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
138 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.00   -11.00  0.33    Y   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
139 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.00   -11.00  0.33    Y   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
140 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.00   -11.00  0.33    Y   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
141 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.00   -11.00  0.33    Y   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
142 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 C   19.00   -11.00  0.33    Y   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
143 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.00   -46.00  -0.67   N   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
144 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.00   -46.00  -0.67   N   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
145 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.00   -46.00  -0.67   N   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
146 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.00   -46.00  -0.67   N   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
147 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.00   -46.00  -0.67   N   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
148 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.00   -46.00  -0.67   N   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
149 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.00   -46.00  -0.67   N   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
150 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.00   -46.00  -0.67   N   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
151 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.00   -46.00  -0.67   N   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
152 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.00   -46.00  -0.67   N   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
153 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 105 P   20.00   -46.00  -0.67   N   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
154 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.00   -96.00  0.26    Y   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
155 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.00   -96.00  0.26    Y   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
156 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.00   -96.00  0.26    Y   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
157 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.00   -96.00  0.26    Y   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
158 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.00   -96.00  0.26    Y   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
159 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.00   -96.00  0.26    Y   101.00  100.00  P   18.00   5   -0.477  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    18.7123
160 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.00   -96.00  0.26    Y   101.00  105.00  C   19.00   -11 0.330   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.2782
161 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.00   -96.00  0.26    Y   101.00  110.00  C   22.00   -96 0.263   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.0872
162 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.00   -96.00  0.26    Y   101.00  115.00  C   25.00   100 0.189   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.1394
163 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.00   -96.00  0.26    Y   101.00  120.00  C   28.00   13  0.108   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.4347
164 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 C   22.00   -96.00  0.26    Y   101.00  125.00  C   30.00   -50 0.018   Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    33.9732
165 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 P   22.65   22.00   -0.74   N   101.00  75.00   P   30.00   -94 -0.005  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    34.5299
166 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 P   22.65   22.00   -0.74   N   101.00  80.00   P   27.89   -25 -0.079  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    28.8801
167 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 P   22.65   22.00   -0.74   N   101.00  85.00   P   25.49   98  -0.123  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    24.4734
168 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 P   22.65   22.00   -0.74   N   101.00  90.00   P   22.65   -97 -0.193  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    21.3099
169 8/9/2015    9/19/2015   101 110 P   22.65   22.00   -0.74   N   101.00  95.00   P   18.94   32  -0.304  Y   0.0249  -4.9837 268.4536    19.3895
```

Comment: That is a lot of reading to find out what the problem is.  Perhaps you should reframe your question to expose it on the first line.

Comment: i thought about that a bit, but I figured the "story" was needed.  If I jumped right into "needing FitVol on each row" i thought it would be more confusing.